# Android: How to lock the focus on EditText?

Tags: android, focus

I have 2 EditText's in my layout.
In the first I shuld put the email adress and in the second the password.
I can look if the email format is good with this code :

```
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()
```

and I would like to block the focus on the email editText until the email format verificationt returns true.

I don't know how to do this, which listener have to be used and how to bloc this focus?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i think below code should help you.

```
editText.setFocusable(false);             
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);             
editText.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: Hi Milos, setFocudable determines whether a view can take focus.
Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html for more detailed explanation.
I suggest you play around with the the 3 codelines and determine which fits the best.

Comment: Thank you @Lars, i have understood these, now the problem is that i have to test if my email adress is in good format whet I am entering a new character, how to d othis, with an setOnKeyListener() ? If yes, how to do it?